# LINQ to SQL "complex" select

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, linq-query-syntax

I have Country=>Ligue=>Team(Name, Score)

I need to select all team Name-Scores from a country.

something like this, does not work )

> query = *from* **ligue** *in* myCountry.Ligues, *from* **team** *in* ligue.Teams 
>              *select* name = **team.Name**, score = **team.Score** *distinct*

EDIT:

VB.NET syntax is preferable.

Comment: relabeled the question since it turns out not to be about linq-to-sql

Comment: @jeroenh I think the question is about LINQ-to-SQL; sorry I didn't provide the syntax you prefer.

Comment: @kirk if you look at serhio's comments, I believe he's mistaking the 'linq query syntax' with 'linq to sql'. Could be wrong though. Also, I don't have any syntax preference, your answer is perfectly valid and I upvoted it, I just added an answer with the VB.Net syntax, as per the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jeroenh's code, that used Kirk's code, here is the working version (VB.NET)

```
  Dim query =  From ligue In myCountry.Ligues
               From team In ligue.Teams
               Select Name = team.Name, Score = team.Score 
               Distinct
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do a simple Select / SelectMany

```
context.Countries.Single(c => c.CountryName == "My Country")
    .Ligues.SelectMany(ligue => ligue.Teams
        .Select(team => new { team.Name, team.Score }))
        .Distinct();
```

Comment: thanks... say, this is not LINQ to SQL, but I will try like this ) and this is not Distinct...

Comment: @serhio I've added a `Distinct`. This **is** LINQ-to-SQL; just that it uses 'method' syntax rather than 'query' syntax.

Comment: this is Linq, but not Linq-to-SQL, because you don't use any "SQL" syntax.

Comment: @serhio wheter it is linq-to-sql or not is not determined by the syntax. It IS linq-2-sql if it works against the linq-to-sql provider.

Comment: @jeroenh: "if it works against the linq-to-sql provider". So, anything indicates from the code above that it works against the linq-to-sql provider.

Comment: @serhio Since your question is labeled linq-to-sql, that can be reasonably assumed.

Comment: @jeroenh: I should recognize that I (incorrectly) used this therm(linq-to-sql) to indicate the specific SQL syntax in the Linq queries. This why I labeled it like this. My fault.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code from Kirk translated to VB10 extension method syntax:

```
dim result = context.Countries.Single(Function(c) c.CountryName = "My Country").
               Ligues.SelectMany(Function(ligue) ligue.Teams).
                      Select(Function(team) new with {team.Name, team.Score }).
                      Distinct()
```

I believe (but am not sure, don't have access to a VB compiler right now) you can write it like this vb.net query syntax

(EDIT my original trial was indeed incorrect, so I corrected the query below:)

```
dim result = From ligue in myCountry.Ligues
             From team in ligue.Teams
             Select team.Name, team.Score Distinct
```